# Can a woman accuse her husband of zina without eye-witness?

Tags: sharia, zina

I came across these verses where a man can accuse his wife of zina in absence of 4 witnesses and it can be averted by invoking God.

Can a woman **accuse** in a similar fashion just as the man can do in the below verses?[24:6-9]

> [6]As for those who accuse their own wives of adultery, but have no
>   other witnesses, let each one four times call God to witness that he is
>   telling the truth, [7] and, the fifth time, call God to reject him if he is
>   lying; [8] punishment shall be averted from his wife if she in turn four
>   times calls God to witness that her husband is lying [9] and, the fifth
>   time, calls God to reject her if he is telling the truth.
>   {Translation from M.A.S Abdel Saleem [link](https://archive.org/details/TheQuranOxfrdWrldClas/page/n263/mode/2up)}

Comment: No. The husband has an interest to be served since lineage of the child will be ascribed to him. A similar interest does not exist for a wife accusing her husband.

Comment: @UmH but zina can take place without pregnancy as well